# Why origin of a screen coordinates have negative value in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

If you run a code below and hover on the top left corner of the screen, you'll see that its coordinates are something like: `x: -12, y: -29`, while the real origin (with a zero coordinates) is placed somewhere else.

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

class Coords extends Component {
  handleFingerMove = ({
    { locationX: x, locationY: y }: nativeEvent
  }) => {
    console.log(x, y)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
        onMoveShouldSetResponder={() => true}
        onResponderGrant={this.handlePressIn}
        onResponderMove={this.handleFingerMove}
        style={{
          height,
          width,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

So the questions are:

- why it's behaving like that?
- is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is it consistent in the emulator AND on device?

Comment: @ChrisGeirman can't test on the device :(

Comment: I'm wondering if it's an emulator thing... is it consistent between emulators (ios vs android)?